# What language should I use for an automatic gear shifting program?

Tags: c, microcontroller

I was thinking about writing a program to automatically change the gear of my bike. It may require a microprocessor, so the question which I had in my mind was: is there any different language for programming a microprocessor or can this be done using C and C++?

Another thing is, regarding the program, can a `switch` statement do my work or do I need a pointer or linked list because the gear works both ways, up and down? I was a bit confused with the `switch` statement thing!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to start programming a microcontroller?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/78744/how-to-start-programming-a-microcontroller)

Comment: Just ride your bike and be happy :)

Comment: Confused with the switch statement and wanting to create a microcontrolled machine to change bicycle gears? Your brains gonna hurt in many ways...

Comment: Be careful about whether you use signed ints or unsigned ints. With signed ints you can go both forwards and backwards, but your maximum speed will only be half that possible with unsigned ints. With unsigned ints you will only be able to go forwards, but your maximum speed will be twice that possible with signed ints.

Comment: @paul r can u let me how does singed int and unsigned int matted here and what relation does it have with speed!!

Comment: @abhinav what @Paul R said was a joke :-)

Comment: @josh u have any possible solution for this question???

Comment: @abhinav what @pmg said in his answer should work fine, right?

Comment: @josh this will work but i got a different idea latter as i'm not much experienced bout the programming so i constructed using while only!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. One solution designed for prototyping and hobby applications is the BASIC Stamp, based on a PIC microcontroller but including an interpreter. It is programmed in BASIC rather than C/C++ if that is what you are looking for. Keep in mind that that there *are* microcontrollers that are "worse" than the one you have; they have to be programmed in assembly language.
2. No pointers or linked lists are required, which is good because microcontrollers usually have a severely limited memory capacity. The `switch` statement will work fine; just remember to include break statements to avoid problems with fall-through. It's also possible to use bit-shifting. Yes, Curd's answer has some truth in it:

   ```
   PORTA = PORTA & ~0x07 | (1 << selected_gear);
   ```

   where selectedGear starts at zero and your bike has three speeds. Just write some code to read the sensor inputs and determine the correct gear that the bike should be in. To do so, you would probably use a [finite state machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_state_machine).

Answer (score 23):

You don't need the switch statement, just use the shift operator:

Shift up:

> gear <<= 1;

Shift down:

> gear >>= 1;

Comment: the gear changes according to the rpm it the rpm reaches 7.4 it shifts up and il lowers to 3 it shifts down and can i program in c

Comment: You forgot to mention that link list is instrumental in tracking the position of the chain, to shift only when all links are aligned correctly.

Comment: The linked list will need to be a circular linked list, too. Make sure your garbage collector can correctly handle cycles.

Comment: @abhinav: 3 rpm means that one revolution takes 20 seconds... Means either you are going very slow or you have a remarkable gear ratio (and very strong legs).

Answer (score 8):

I'd probably use neither pointer, link list or switch to write it tough.

First thing you need to know is what inputs you have and how to get them.
Then you need to know what outputs you can send and how.

Supposing you can read the rpm as a C variable, and that another variable controls the gear, this should work:

```
while (1) {
    if (rpm <= 3) chggear(-1);
    if (rpm >= 7.4) chggear(+1);
}
```

where the function `chggear` would change the gear and wait a convenient amount of time to make sure the next gear is engaged before returning to the loop.

```
int chggear(int direction) {
    gear += direction;
    sleep(10); /* wait for gear to engage */
    return gear; /* return currently engaged gear */
}
```

---

**Edit** you can also change directly to a specific gear no matter what the gearbox is doing:

```
int jumptogear(int geartojump) {
    gear = geartojump;
}
```

and use it like this

```
if (breaking) jumptogear(1); /* and possibly break gearbox */
```

Comment: i have another situation here if the gear is changed now(increased) and and suddenly you applied the break bringing down the rpm or say it was suppose to come down to first gear from somewhere 3 or 4th gear but it waits after every change of gear..how will we handle this situation

Comment: You're beginning to add too much confusion ... pretty soon you're going to need a Real Time Operating System ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_operating_system ).

Comment: Bike gears are generally sequential.  +1, -1 is probably enough.  Unless you have more than one chain ring in which case you'll need some algorithm to do the changes in sequence.  Also, there needs to be a way to detect free wheeling.  If you stop peddling , you do not necessarily want to change down.  In fact derailleurs can't be changed if you are not peddling.

Answer (score 6):

Other than being a really bad idea and a potentially extremely dangerous "experiment" to attempt to program your own microprocessor to change the gears on your bike automatically, you may find it useful to look into something called Arduino.

Arduino is an "open-source hardware" board that can be programmed in C, C++ or C# (depending on which one you buy). It plugs directly into your computer via USB for programming. You can hook up pretty much anything you like to it - motors, servos, sensors, etc...

Comment: but it has no practical use!!i was looking for thing which has some practical use!!anyhow thanks for the advice and i'm looking forward for arduino

Answer (score 4):

This doesn't need any data structures at all (or any data); it's a finite state machine. Of course it would be much easier to do just with simple electronics and no computer.

Answer (score 0):

@ pgm @ jeremy: here is what i thought bout the same question,in motor bikes generally the gear shift takes place at different rpm for different gear such as it switches to 2nd when rpm is 5.5 and switchs to 3 when rpm is 6.2..so here is what i thought

```
while(gear==1)    //here gear value will deffer//
{  
    if(rpm>=5.5)      //**to check if it exceeded the rpm level**//
    {
        gear=gear+1;     //**increments the gear value**//
        sleep(10);        //**PROVIDE TIME FOR CHANGE OF GEAR (it must be done after returning the value)**//
        return gear;        //**returns value of gear**//
    }
    else if(rpm<3)        //**checks the lower level of rpm**//
    {
        gear=gear-;       //**decrementing**//
        sleep(10);
        eturn gear; 
    }
    else (rpm>3&&<5.5)    //checks whether it is in limit or not//
    {
        return gear;
    }
}
```

This kind of code can be written for different gear but the thing here where I'm confused with ,how do i provide rest(time for changing the gear mechanically) after every gear shift..it should be done after returning gear value..

- List item`enter code here`*emphasized text*

Comment: If I post here a program that compiles and "feels like" it should work would you program your gearbox with it and drive around on your bike? Or would you put your life in my hands? :-) I suggest you get some more experience with C (or other language) before writing an automatic gear shifter.

Comment: @pmg sure i'm try to gain more exp with the language...as i was a student and was new to this programming world i thought i'll try doing something..can u recomend me any book for c and c++

Comment: i wrothe a program here but why am i gettingit in the paragraph format!!

Comment: @abhinav: Looks like you figured it out.  Are you sure you want an `else` with a condition, not an `else if`?

Comment: @ bill well that will be else if and what do u say bout the sleep should it come before or after returning the value..